# fullCalendar is not a function and events are not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, calendar, fullcalendar

I am trying to run a very basic script that uses the interaction plugin of fullcalendar. I want the users to input events via marking the right date or time in the calendar (select). After marking for example 5th August to 9th August, a prompt would aks for the event title. User types in "vacation" and the script automatically streams the information "from... to" to the event data. But the problem is, after marking the date and typing in the event title, the event does not appear on the calendar.

As long as the site isn't being reloaded, I also cannot mark a new event. In addition, the firefox browser console says fullCalender is not a function. The majority of what is to be found on the web about this issue is that it is most likely the library, which isn't being loaded properly, but according to the browser console its loaded properly indeed. The calendar is visible and I am able to select the date, therefore I do not see the problem. I already put hours into this....

I already tried to change the library from local to CDN, that didn't change no thing.

Here is the code, that I've mixed out of the documentation of fullcalendar and this code pen: https://codepen.io/JSFanatik/pen/QVvxvw

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src='/calendar/fullcalendar/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src='/calendar/fullcalendar/dist/core/main.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='/calendar/fullcalendar/dist/interaction/main.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='/calendar/fullcalendar/dist/daygrid/main.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='/calendar/fullcalendar/dist/timegrid/main.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='/calendar/fullcalendar/dist/core/locales/de.js'></script>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

                plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
                locale: "de",
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                }, 
                selectable: true,
                navLinks: true,
                defaultView: "dayGridMonth",
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: false,
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: false, 

                select: function(start, end) {
                    var title = prompt("Event Title?");
                    var eventData;
                    if (title) {
                        eventData = {
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end
                        };        
                        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("renderEvent", eventData, true); // stick? = true
                    }
                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");
                },

                eventRender: function(event, element) {
                    element
                    .find(".fc-content")
                    .prepend("<span class='closeon material-icons'>&#xe5cd;</span>");
                    element.find(".closeon").on("click", function() {
                        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("removeEvents", event._id);
                    });
                },

                eventClick: function(calEvent) {
                    var title = prompt("Change Title:", calEvent.title);
                    calEvent.title = title;
                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("updateEvent", calEvent);
                }
            });
            calendar.render();
        });
    </script>
```

I hope you guys can help me with that. I have to say I don't know much about JavaScript, I just have build a website and thought this calendar would be a very useful addition. Thanks!

Comment: Incidentally, that's JavaScript, not Java. They're completely unrelated languages.

Comment: As I don't know how to edit the question again, I have to say that jquery is included

Comment: There's an [edit] button under your question - you can use that or the link I just supplied. Also, I'm not sure why you think whether jQuery is included is relevant. jQuery is just a JavaScript library - it still has nothing whatsoever to do with Java.

Comment: I have checked with firefox v. 66 and chrome v. 75.. it seems to be working fine. No error on either browser. Which browser version you are using ?

Comment: Look at how you call `calendar.render();`. Notice a difference between that and `$("#calendar").fullCalendar("updateEvent"...`? Now read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3#initialization . fullCalendar is no longer implemented as a jQuery plugin. Make sure you don't mix up the syntax for version 3 and version 4.  Lastly read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3#event-model to check exactly how you need to replace your v3 method calls. Everything you need to know to fix this error is already in the fullCalendar documentation...

Comment: P.S. Surely you noticed a big difference between the code above and the code in that codePen, in terms of how the calendar was initialised and the options being passed in? The syntax structure is significantly different.

Answer (score 0):

i've been had same issue, am not sure what cause my problem. but when i check at the debug console it shows "[Violation] 'load' handler took 166ms".
i solve my problem with moving out the code outside method : document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { ..

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
calendar.refetchEvents();
calendar.render();
```

Comment: No, those were hints. In order to render the fullCalendar, he needs to refetch events and render it.